# TypeError: e is undefined, while adding dynamic dropdown list in the search field of jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2, struts2-jquery-grid, struts2-jquery-plugin

I am trying to add a dynamic dropdown list in the search field of jqgrid.
My code details is ::

in jsp page :

```
<s:url var="selecturl" action="selectAction"/> 

<sjg:gridColumn name="lastName" index="lastName" title="Last Name" sortable="true"  search="true" searchtype="select" searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','ne'], dataUrl : '%{selecturl}'}"/>
```

in struts.xml :

```
    <action name="selectAction" class="customer.editgridentry.JsonTable">  
        <result name="success" type="json" />                
    </action>
```

in JsonTable class ::

```
    public class JsonTable extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

    public Map mySearchValuesList;// = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Map<String, String> getMySearchValuesList() {
        return mySearchValuesList;
    }

    public void setMySearchValuesList(Map<String, String> mySearchValuesList) {
        this.mySearchValuesList = mySearchValuesList;
    }

@Override
public void prepare() throws Exception {
    mySearchValuesList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mySearchValuesList.put("1", "One");
    mySearchValuesList.put("2", "Two");
    mySearchValuesList.put("3", "Three");
}
    ........
    }
```

But this is showing :

**TypeError: e is undefined**

Can anyone please tell me, where the problem is ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the request being sent and the response being received. (for Chrome->Developer Tools->Network tab)

Comment: While opening the Add window / edit window, the select action is called and 200 Ok response is received 

But while opening the search window, it doesn't call the select action

What might prevent the action to be called ?

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

[Showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action) returns a complete select tag, not just JSON

[image]

The [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SearchGrid) clearly says : **create an Action that returns a Select Box with searchable values**

For e.g. you can do something like below

```
<action name="selectAction" class="customer.editgridentry.JsonTable">  
        <result name="success">/select.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**select.jsp**

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<s:select list="mySearchValuesList" name="lastName"/>
```

Comment: Thnx



<action name="selectAction" class="customer.editgridentry.JsonTable">  
            <result name="success">content/select.jsp</result> 
</action> 

and 



editoptions="{ dataUrl : '%{selecturl}' }"



works fine for add and edit, but shows the same error (TypeError: e is undefined) for dynamic dropdown in search window.

for search option i have added : 

searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','ne'], dataUrl : '%{selecturl}'}"

Comment: search is not supposed to work like that. I guess you didn't checked the [showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action). It doesn't make any sense if search will be a dropdown and if you need one, you have to implement your own custom-search instead of relying on grid's internal search.